# How to check if $ E [\exp \{ \int_0^t \frac{Y_u^2}{1+Y_u^2}du \}]< \infty $

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance-mathematics, expected-value

$dY_t=2Y_tdt+2\sqrt{1+Y_t^2}dW_t$ where $W_t$ is $P-$Brownian motion (Wiener process).

I have defined a new measure $Q$ where the Kernel density (In Girsanov theorem) is
$$ \phi_t = \frac{Y_t}{\sqrt{1+Y_t^2}}
$$
Now I need to assure that the Novikov condition is satisfied. Hence I need to make sure:
$$
E^P [\exp \{
\int_0^t \frac{Y_u^2}{1+Y_u^2}du
\}]< \infty.
$$
Is it? **Is it possible to show that and how can I show that?**

Comment: I don’t understand the first equation. Please correct

Comment: $dY_t$ instead of $Y_t$. Thanks for the reminder! I have now corrected.

Comment: Note that $0 \le \frac{Y_u^2}{1+Y_u^2} < 1$. Then $\exp\int_0^t \frac{Y_u^2}{1+Y_u^2} du < \exp(t)$, and $E\left( \exp\int_0^t \frac{Y_u^2}{1+Y_u^2} du\right) \le  \exp(t)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make the change of variable $Y_t = \sinh U_t$ and apply Ito then you immediately get

$$dU_t = 2dW_t$$

so the solution of your SDE is $$Y_t = \sinh\left(2W_t + C\right)$$

with $C$ a constant.

Then to answer your question is suffices to notice that

$$\frac{Y_u}{\sqrt{1+Y_u^2}}=\tanh(U_t)$$

which is bounded therefore your expression is finite since the integrand is bounded.